# How can I use Pycharm to launch a static site on localhost?

Tags: pycharm

I mainly use Pycharm for Python projects, but have found it pretty nice to use for basic front end development. I have a static site that I would like to launch at localhost at some port. I had this working before, but now it stopped working out of nowhere. Any idea on how I can modify my settings or run configurations to get this going again?

Answer (score 2):

It works in PyCharm the same way it works in WebStorm. Here's a [blog post about the built-in server](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/).

You just need to open an HTML file and select View -> Open in Browser from main menu.
The port for the built-in server is configured in Settings -> Debugger -> JavaScript.